# Java Compiler Error: not a statement

Tags: java

Hi I am new to java programming. I want to write a java program that gets the first name and the surname initials of the user. My code is:

```
public class MyProgram {
public void start() {
    String name = getNameFromUser();
    char firstNameInitials = getInitials(name);
    char surnameInitials = getInitials(name);
    printInitials(firstNameInitials, surnameInitials);
}
private String getNameFromUser() {
    System.out.print("Please enter your name: ");
    String name = Keyboard.readInput();
    return name;
}
private char getInitials(String name) {
    char firstNameInitials = name.charAt(0);
    int indexOfSpace = name.indexOf(" ");
    char surnameInitials = name.charAt(indexOfSpace + 1);

    return firstNameInitials; surnameInitials;
}

private void printInitials(String firstNameInitials, String surnameInitials){
    System.out.print("your initials are: " + firstNameInitials +". " + surnameInitials +".");
}
}
```

i am getting an error message, i dont know what it means:

```
Error: not a statement.
```

The error seems to be at line 18, at the return statement. 
I have tried to fix it but have failed. Any suggestions how can I fix this please?

Comment: What do you believe that semicolon is supposed to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
return firstNameInitials; surnameInitials;
```

you can not return multiple char like this. Instead use a char array to return

For example you can return like this

```
private char[] getInitials(String name) {
    char firstNameInitials = name.charAt(0);
    int indexOfSpace = name.indexOf(" ");
    char surnameInitials = name.charAt(indexOfSpace + 1);

    char[] result  = {firstNameInitials, surnameInitials};
    return result;
}
```

And call it like

```
char[] a = getInitials(name);
char firstNameInitials = a[0];
char surnameInitials = a[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can return only one  value at a time.You can not return more than one value

Create a class that holds multiple values you need. In your method, return an object that's an instance of that class.

This way, you still return one object. In Java, you cannot return more than one object, whatever that may be.

```
public class TestVO {

    private char irstNameInitials;
    private char surnameInitials;
    public char getIrstNameInitials() {
        return irstNameInitials;
    }
    public void setIrstNameInitials(char irstNameInitials) {
        this.irstNameInitials = irstNameInitials;
    }
    public char getSurnameInitials() {
        return surnameInitials;
    }
    public void setSurnameInitials(char surnameInitials) {
        this.surnameInitials = surnameInitials;
    }    
}


private TestVOgetInitials(String name) {
char firstNameInitials = name.charAt(0);
int indexOfSpace = name.indexOf(" ");
char surnameInitials = name.charAt(indexOfSpace + 1);

   TestVO vo = new TestVO();
   vo.setIrstNameInitials(firstNameInitials);
    vo.setSurnameInitials(surnameInitials);

return vo; ;
```

}

Comment: @tPSR hanks how can i do it?

Comment: create a vo class.Do you know how to create

Comment: vo class? no havent heard of it before.

Comment: means value object or dto(data transfer object)

Answer (score 0):

error:

```
return firstNameInitials; surnameInitials;
```

return only one value;

```
 printInitials(firstNameInitials, surnameInitials);
```

either convert the function to take char as parameter or change the arguments to string.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. You made some simple mistakes.

```
public class Testprg
{
   public void start()
   {
    String name = getNameFromUser();
    char firstNameInitials = getFirstNameInitials(name);
    char surnameInitials = getSurNameInitials(name);
    printInitials(firstNameInitials, surnameInitials);
   }

   private String getNameFromUser()
   {
    System.out.print("Please enter your name: ");
    String name = Keyboard.readInput();
    return name;
   }

   private char getFirstNameInitials(String name)
   {
    char firstNameInitials = name.charAt(0);

    return firstNameInitials;
   }

   private char getSurNameInitials(String name)
   {
    int indexOfSpace = name.indexOf(" ");
    char surnameInitials = name.charAt(indexOfSpace + 1);

    return surnameInitials;
   }

   private void printInitials(char firstNameInitials, char surnameInitials)
   {
    System.out.print("your initials are: " + firstNameInitials + ". " + surnameInitials + ".");
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class ShowCurrentTime
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        //obtain the total milliseconds since Midnight, Sept 1, 2016
        long totalMilliseconds - System.currentTimeMillis();

        //total seconds
        long totalSeconds = totalMilliseconds / 1000;

        long currentSeconds = (int) (totalSeconds) % 60;

        //obtain total minutes
        long totalMinutes = totalSeconds / 60;

        //obtain current minute
        long currentMinute = (int) (totalMinutes) % 60;

        long toalHours = totalMinute / 60;

        long currentHour = (int) (totalHours % 24);

        System.out.println ("Current time is " + currenHour + ":" 
                                + currentMinute + " " + " " + currentSeconds 
                                + "GMT");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.